# HP hs2340 HSPA+ MobileBroadband on HP mini 210-4160ew mobile internet illness

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, internet, hp, mobile-broadband

1. The hardware is recognized with success.
2. in iwconfig command it is: usb0
3. The OS is: Ubuntu 12.04 the most up to date from ubuntu site
4. in network manager is an info: mobile connection: not powered on
5. At starting of loading desktop, i'm asked to insert a PIN to unlock modem, i write PIN and nothing hapens
6. set up manual connection doesn't help
7. Internet vendor: Orange (Poland)
8. The card is unlocked (for sure)
9. WiFi and ethernet cable internet works perfectly
10. I'm a newbie in linux
11. I'm asking for the resolve of problem - step by step
12. I'm really sorry for my english
13. I don't really now what to do to have an internet on my netbook via modem

All the best here from Poland

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a dual boot Ubuntu / Windows, you can test if it's with the power management.

On Windows you can power the modem with the HP connection manager. Configure it so that modem is not powered off on exit, then reboot.

If it's working after reboot, you have the same issue as I did:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/838757

Comment: I'm sorry i dont have a dual boot. I found this article before i wrote here. But being in touch with this article, i'll try on virtual machine, although i dont think that virtual machine will recognize my modem correctly  - i'll get u all know what happend. Thanks for advice, anybody has some more suggestions?